# OnChange function of input type radio in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am having input tags with radio type

[image]

```
               <div className="col-md-12">
                    <div className="form-group clearfix">
                      <label htmlFor="" className="col-md-2 control-label">Authentication</label>
                      <div className="col-md-8">

                        <input type="radio"  name="authentication" value="No Authentication" onChange={this.Authentication.bind(this)} />
                        No Authentication


                      <input type="radio"  name="authentication" value="Master Credentials" onChange={this.Authentication.bind(this)} />
                      Master Credentials


                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

And the onChange function

```
Authentication(e) {
this.setState({ authentication: e.target.value });

 }
```

onChange is getting called only for the first time when i click on second time onChange is not getting called not able to identify what is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `checked` props like below:

```
<div className="col-md-12">
  <div className="form-group clearfix">
    <label htmlFor="" className="col-md-2 control-label">
      Authentication
    </label>
    <div className="col-md-8">
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="authentication"
        value="No Authentication"
        checked={this.state.authentication === "No Authentication"}
        onChange={this.Authentication.bind(this)}
      />
      No Authentication
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="authentication"
        value="Master Credentials"
        onChange={this.Authentication.bind(this)}
        checked={this.state.authentication === "Master Credentials"}
      />
      Master Credentials
    </div>
  </div>
</div>;
```

[Demo code](https://codesandbox.io/s/1161y9oql).

Comment: I'll add documentation link in my answer, right now seems official site is down or something. Giving 502.

Comment: Thank you.but previously in other applications i used same way it worked there but I dont why here i faced this